# What is Best Practice to Create Mobile Webview with Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webview

I have a mobile app project that created with VueJS. My boss wanted the app to run in webview for some reason, so I built it with VueJS. My question is, does anyone have a recommended framework or method to use to do this?

I had used flutter with [InAppWebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) plugin to wrap the web. But does anyone have other recommendation? Thank you